# ClojureScript - Failing to iterate over the ns-unmap function

Tags: clojurescript

I'm having trouble getting something to work in ClojureScript that works in Clojure no problem.

```
(defn unmap [nspace & vars]
  (doseq [var vars] (ns-unmap nspace var)))
```

Usage as:

```
(unmap 'some.nspace 'vars 'to 'be 'removed)
```

You can also make unmap a macro so you don't have to quote everything. All it does is iterate over a list of symbols and pluck their bindings from a given namespace.

Neither the macro form, or the unmap function work in ClojureScript (they work fine in Clojure). I get the following error when trying to define the above function.

Unexpected error (AssertionError) macroexpanding cljs.core/ns-unmap.
Assert failed: Arguments to ns-unmap must be quoted symbols

Not sure if this is a bug. It seems like ClojureScript is looking for a type hint. If anyone knows how to get this to work it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ClojureScript, the `ns-unmap`  macro is designed to be used at the REPL to manipulate both runtime and compiler state used in the implementation of namespaces at dev time.

The symbols passed to `ns-unmap` need to be known at compile time in order for it to properly manipulate compiler state at macroexpansion time.

This problem can be solved by defining a macro which expands to a `do` containing each of the desired `ns-unmap` invocations.

Here is an example:

```
(defmacro unmap [nspace & vars]
 `(do
   ~@(map (fn [var] 
           `(ns-unmap ~nspace ~var)) 
      vars)))
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I've read docs on macros in cljs vs. clj, but I don't think I really get it. You say that the symbols need to be known at compile time, but does that mean that repl defined functions are JS evaled in a way that is outside the normal compilation process? In other words, repl functions can be JS runtime generated but underlying macros are static as in compiled in the JVM before hand?

Comment: @MFave Macros are indeed associated with compile time and are processed independent of any particular JavaScript runtime, even when at the REPL. The `ns-unmap` macro is special in that its arguments need to be quoted symbols that are known at compile time.